# How can I convert a Bitmap to a 1D byte array and vice versa in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, image-processing, bitmap, bitmapdata

I wrote the following methods,

```
public static byte[] BitmapToByteArray(Bitmap image)
        {
            byte[] returns = null;
            if (image.PixelFormat == PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed)
            {
                BitmapData bitmapData = image.LockBits(
                                                new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height),
                                                ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                                                image.PixelFormat);
                int noOfPixels = image.Width * image.Height;
                int colorDepth = Bitmap.GetPixelFormatSize(image.PixelFormat);
                int step = colorDepth / 8;
                byte[] bytes = new byte[noOfPixels * step];
                IntPtr address = bitmapData.Scan0;
                Marshal.Copy(address, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                ////////////////////////////////////////////////
                ///
                returns = (byte[])bytes.Clone();
                ///
                ////////////////////////////////////////////////
                Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, address, bytes.Length);
                image.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("8bpp indexed image required");
            }
            return returns;
        }
```

And,

```
public static Bitmap ByteArrayToBitmap(byte[] bytes, int width, int height, PixelFormat pixelFormat)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, pixelFormat);
            BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bitmap.PixelFormat);
            int colorDepth = Bitmap.GetPixelFormatSize(pixelFormat);
            int noOfChannels = colorDepth / 8;
            IntPtr address = bitmapData.Scan0;
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //
            Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, address, width * height * noOfChannels);
            //
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);

            return bitmap;
        }
```

They seem to be not working,

[image]

**What has been the problem do you think?**

**N.B.**

Driver program,

```
public class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string [] args)
    {
        Bitmap inputBmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(@"cameraman.gif");

        byte[] bytes = Converter.BitmapToByteArray(inputBmp);//byte[65536]

        Bitmap outputBmp = Converter.ByteArrayToBitmap(bytes, inputBmp.Width, inputBmp.Height, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);

        PictureDisplayForm f = new PictureDisplayForm(inputBmp, outputBmp);
        f.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: It has the file header, the bitmap header and the palette included as well.  As required by the BMP file format.  I'd hate to guess at what "an exception" might mean but something probably goes wrong when you interpret this extra data as image pixels

Comment: The second method dumps the raw file to the buffer, which is not at all what you need. It must be interpreted to yield a bitmap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay.

I have solved it.

```
public static byte[] BitmapToByteArray(Bitmap image)
        {
            byte[] returns = null;
            if (image.PixelFormat == PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed)
            {
                BitmapData bitmapData = image.LockBits(
                                                new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height),
                                                ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                                                image.PixelFormat);
                int noOfPixels = image.Width * image.Height;
                int colorDepth = Bitmap.GetPixelFormatSize(image.PixelFormat);
                int step = colorDepth / 8;
                byte[] bytes = new byte[noOfPixels * step];
                IntPtr address = bitmapData.Scan0;
                Marshal.Copy(address, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                ////////////////////////////////////////////////
                ///
                returns = (byte[])bytes.Clone();
                ///
                ////////////////////////////////////////////////
                Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, address, bytes.Length);
                image.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("8bpp indexed image required");
            }
            return returns;
        }

        public static Bitmap ByteArray1dToBitmap(byte[] bytes, int width, int height)
        {
            PixelFormat pixelFormat = PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed;
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, pixelFormat);

            // Set the palette for gray shades
            ColorPalette pal = bitmap.Palette;
            for (int i = 0; i < pal.Entries.Length; i++)
            {
                pal.Entries[i] = Color.FromArgb(i, i, i);
            }
            bitmap.Palette = pal;

            BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, pixelFormat);
            int colorDepth = Bitmap.GetPixelFormatSize(pixelFormat);
            int noOfChannels = colorDepth / 8;

            unsafe
            {
                byte* address = (byte*)bitmapData.Scan0;
                int area = width * height;
                int size = area * noOfChannels;
                for (int i = 0; i < area; i++)
                {
                    address[i] = bytes[i];//262144 bytes
                }
            }

            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);

            return bitmap;
        }
```

Comment: You should really take the stride into account though... might mess things up if your saved image is compacted to not align its lines to 4 bytes. Also note that the calculation method you have there does not work for 4bpp or 1bpp indexed images since you divide the color depth by 8 in advance.